# Anyone using something like HTMLAgilityPack to generate HTML for MVC3 helpers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

It may be overkill and the library is not technically designed to generate HTML (although I have used it to generate HTML for ASP.Net custom controls and it works great), but I was wondering if anyone is using this or another library to generate the HTML inside their helpers.

I know a lot of people use a standard StringBuilder and it works great. I was curious to know if anyone else has used something other than it.

Comment: I was hoping to see more activity on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I have found that using HTML agility pack to generate the HTML was quite useful. I plan on adding it to my architecture for building out my helpers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use TagBuilder class as the name of the class suggests, enables you to easily build HTML tags.

Comment: i did look into the HtmlTextWriter and TagBuilder, but I also liked some of the extra features that the AgilityPack comes with. I suppose, in the end it is all about preference and not adding too much overhead. Thank you for suggesting that!